# How to create one Histogram with the input of many Pictures

Tags: python, image, image-processing, histogram

image processing

I took 58 pictures of a rotating object with the same exposure and distance, now I want to create a **histogram** of the brightness distribution on x and y axis of the pixel columns or pixel rows in **Python**, over **all pictures**. I am looking for tips for the implementation, currently I have read in a list of the images, alternatively I have heard about batches.

Thank you

Comment: You can upload all your pictures together with the `glob` library, then transform them into arrays with `matplotlib` or `pil`, and then perform your pixel operations with `numpy`. I hope this helps a little.

Comment: So if you got a single new image where each pixel in it represents the mean across all 58 images at that position, would that be the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are probably dealing with data provided by a CT-Scan / Synchrotron. As part of my PhD I have sometimes encounter this problem  and I had to develop a routine to generate this. I will give you some hints to achieve it.

The most straight forward way to extract the histogram of your set of images is:

1) Convert all your images to the same type (In my case, I normally convert them to a greyscale of 8-bit ).

2) Declare a global histogram in which you will add the counts for each greyvalue for each image. I declared a 2-column array. In the first column I wil just write the greyvalues from 0 to 255. In the second column I will store their respective counts. I did so in order to be easier to plot later

```
histogram_global = np.zeros((256,2))
```

3) Extract the histogram of each image of your stack. Fo doing so, you must:

3.1) Open the image with the library PIL and onvert each Image to a an array, where each value of the array is a grescale value between 0-255 for 8-bit images.

```
im=Image.open(image_path)
a = np.array(im.getdata())
```

3.2) By means of the library "Numpy", you obtain the counts of for each greyvalue, i.e, the histogram for that picture.

```
bins_hist = list(range(0,257))
hist_image = np.histogram(a, bins=bins_hist)
counts = hist_image[0]
```

3.3) Add these counts to the global histogram you declared in the beginning.

4) Plot your global histogram.

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
color = 'tab:red'
ax1.bar(histogram_i[:,0], histogram_i[:,1], color=color)
```

As said, this process works with 8-bit (greyscale) pictures. However, if you are dealing with RGB pictures, the process is similar, but instead of creating just one global histogram, you will need to create three global histograms, one per channel; red, blue and green. The rest is similar.